# Pencil Modelling

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Okay so, I've been trying to make a pencil, but sadly I have failed (obviously). I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NgMlruLsc8&t=160s) video tutorial and instead of ending up with this:

[image]

I ended up making this, even though I have followed every single step... I think.

[image]

I would be thankful if someone helps me out with this or tell me another way of making a pencil.

Comment: your boolean settings are wrong. You want the *difference* not the intersect.

Comment: I will try it out again later...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Booleans are cool but not always the only way. Especially since Booleans don't like it when verts or edges sit exactly on top of each other. Then you need to marginally move or rotate them. Here's another way.

Create a mesh cone. Make sure the vertices are a multiple of six for a six sided pencil. Adjust the length of the tip with 'Depth'. 'Fill Type':Nothing

[image: It's a conedy]

In Edit Mode select the entire base and use Checker Deselect. In my case, Nth Selection = 6. For a 60 vertex cone, this would be 60 / 6 = 10.

[image: Checker deselect is so cool.]

Duplicate the 6 verts with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> , use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to stop translation and keep them in place, make an ngon out of them with <kbd>F</kbd> and throw them out with <kbd>P</kbd> 'selection'.

[image: just like the honey bees.]

Select everything and use Knife Project with <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> .

[image: Snip]

Invert the selection with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and delete the verts.

[image: spring cleaning]

<kbd>E</kbd> xtrude the bottom verts down.

[image: Surprisingly, long pencils don't cost more than short pencils]

Scale them flat with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>. Fill with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: aaand, a watertight mesh at last]

Finishing touches: Use the knife tool to make a straight cut in order to make the tip, select all and recalc the normals with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Assign 3 materials to the corresponding faces.

[image: finnish...or swedish]

Find a good home for the stray hexagon.

Answer (score 6):

Go in the modifier tab and in the object below change from BMesh to Carve and you will get the similar result.

[image]

Final result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hm. You are using newer version of blender, that has improved booleans. It's mean that trick with inverted normals will not work.

Try Operation difference instead:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried all 3, none of them worked. I'll try again though and I'll be back to you.